# How find the minimum of $ab+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b>0$ such that $$a+b\le 1$$ Find the minimum of
$$ab+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}$$

My try: 
I can find this minimum，use Holder inequality

$$(\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2})(a+b)^2\ge (1+1)^3=8$$
But 
$$ab\le \dfrac{(a+b)^2}{4}\le\dfrac{1}{4}$$
so for 
$$ab+\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}$$ minimum I can't find it,thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here care must be taken while using AM-GM so that the constraint and equality condition is not violated.  Hence rewrite the objective as:

$$\left(\frac12 ab+ \frac12 ab+\frac{1}{32a^2}+\frac{1}{32b^2}\right)+ \frac{31}{32}\left( \frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}\right)$$
The first part is a sum of four terms with constant product.  Hence this achieves minimum when each term is the same.  Hence for this part,
$$\implies 16ab^3=16a^3b=1 \implies a=b=\tfrac12$$

So for the first part, the minimum is $\frac12$. For the second part, we have
$$\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2} = \left(\frac1a-\frac1b\right)^2+\frac2{a^2b^2} \ge 0+ \frac8{(a+b)^2} \ge 8$$
which is also achieved when $a=b=\frac12$.

Hence the minimum of the objective within the constraints is achieved when $a=b=\frac12$, and the value is $\frac{33}4$.

Comment: Sorry I don't see what's unique about the first line, couldn't we also have chosen $$\left(\frac12 ab+ \frac12 ab+\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2b^2}\right)+ \frac12\left( \frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}\right)$$ where the LH term is also a sum of four terms with constant product?

Comment: @smci Sure.  However if you complete the exercise with your choice, you should get a lower bound, but not the minimum.  This is because equality is not possible with your choice, while keeping $a+b \leqslant 1$...

Comment: Why is equality not possible with that? I don't see what method you used to choose that decomposition to guarantee minimum value. Why couldn't it equally have been $$\left(\frac12 ab+ \frac12 ab+\frac{1}{128a^2}+\frac{1}{128b^2}\right)+ \frac{127}{128}\left( \frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}\right)$$

Comment: @smci same answer as above.  Try it out, can you get equality?  The only way to get equality and satisfy the constraints is with the choice I used.

Comment: Oh I see. You applied the constraints $a+b\le 1$ and $a=b$ at a minimum to infer that $ab^3=a^3b=1/16$, then that dictates your LH term. The remainder goes into the RH term.

Comment: @smci  Precisely.  The $a=b = \frac12$ is an initial guess, which drives the terms used for AM-GM, and gets rigorously proven by the end of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM
$$16ab+16ab+a^{-2}+b^{-2}\ge16$$
But
$$2\sqrt{ab}\le a+b\le 1\implies ab\le\frac14\implies -31ab\ge-\frac{31}4$$
Summing we get, with equality iff $a=b=\frac12$
$$S\ge\frac{33}4$$

Comment: Again, when is equality achieved, and is that in the feasible region?

Comment: @Macavity *facepalms* well,  I am deleting this as that is a good point.

Comment: @Macavity I fixed it, I think so. (And thank you very much for the spotting!)

Comment: Yes +1, I just posted the same minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$ab+\frac 1{a^2}+\frac 1{b^2}=ab+\frac 1{a^2}+\frac 1{b^2}+\frac {2}{ab}-\frac {2}{ab}$$
$$\Rightarrow ab+\frac 1{a^2}+\frac 1{b^2}=ab+(\frac 1a-\frac 1b)^2+\frac 2{ab}$$
Let us analyse the RHS:
The minumum value of $(\frac 1a-\frac 1b)^2$ is 0 when a=b and the minumum value of $ab+\frac 2{ab}$ is $2\sqrt 2$(A.M.-G.M inequality). Hence the minimum value of the required expression is $2\sqrt 2$

Comment: Note that this minimum is obtained by $a=b=\sqrt[4]{2}$

Comment: How is it $\sqrt[4]{2}$

Comment: Even if it is achieved there, how is $a+b \le 1$ satisfied?

Comment: My mistake. This minimum is not achieved on the specified domain, then. The minimum on this domain is $33/4$ which is, of course, way bigger than this.